# Can effect of gravity be broken (counteracted) by electric force?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, levitation

Can we make a jacket using an electronic circuit that uses electric force to cancel the effect of gravity so that we get lifted in air.

Comment: Kinda like [Millikan's Oil Drop Experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) ?

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_levitation), but it's not very stable.

Comment: What about a magnetic field that repels you from the ground, consequently allowing you to levitate.....

Comment: Not pacemaker safe btw

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can levitate yourself with an electric force, however there are a few caveats:

1. The ground beneath you needs to be charged
2. You need to be in a very dry area (i.e., very low humidity)
3. You are okay with levitation heights being on the order of a few $\rm mm$

We're likely not going to have an electrostatically-levitated objects due to the small levitation heights, but it is most certainly practical.

As a fun aside, there is a [website that shows off some home-made electrostatic levitation](http://www.sciencetoymaker.org/electrostaticLevitation/) experiments.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer not really.

There are <strike>2</strike> 3 ways to cancel gravity,

```
-one you create anti gravitation particles which no human scientist has ever produced,
 let alone observed. (or where they its own antiparticle i don't remember)

-two you propel your self with air,
so basically if with electronic jacket you mean a electric powered airplane then yes

-use photons like a highly powered laser beam
```

Electromagnetic forces only have a strong interaction between 2 charged entities the earth is neutral so therefore it would be slightly problematic.

edit

Electrostatic levitation is a process that can only apply when both the person floating and the surface he is floating above are oppositely charged. so there can not be a singular jacket that can help you levitate. the maglev train uses electromagnet force to not only levitate but also propel itself at high speed without touching the ground. This process requires a rail and it cannot hover on it own.

p.s 
In physics there is a concept called a antimatter engine that emits a beam of photons to propel itself, because photons are but excitation's  of the electromagnet field a jacket having a mini antimatter engine could in theory propel you.

Comment: There are two comments above that give two examples to gravitational force being beaten by electrostatic forces.

Comment: I edited my reply with a note electrostatic forces. It do not consider that free floating. A antimatter engine is however a nice solution even thew not practical .

Comment: Electrostatic levitation is a **real** thing, your first sentence says it is not possible which is patently false.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos No not really it is not false. the op referred to a jacket worn only by the person. Electrostatic levitation can only levitate a particle if the ground is also charged. like in the maglev train case. I simply assumed he was asking if it was possible to levitate without circuits on the ground assisting you